# When does prefetch cache get re-populated after publishing?

Tags: publishing, caching

I'm currently running Sitecore with separated CM and CD servers/DBs.
I'm aware that prefetch cache get re-polulated when server restart.

This Sitecore documentation state that 
https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc62keywords/cache_configuration_reference_us.pdf

> Sitecore clears one or more caches after each publishing operation.
>   In environments that consist of a single Sitecore instance providing both content management and
>   content delivery, Sitecore clears the site HTML (output) caches after each publishing operation. In
>   environments that separate a content management instance from some number of content delivery
>   instances, Sitecore clears the site HTML (output) caches and all other caches after each publishing
>   operation.

My question is whether the prefetch be immediately re-populated after a publish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefetch cache is not repopulated after a publish, it is repopulated just when you restart your site.

**Prefetch Cache**

Prefetch caches contain items that Sitecore accesses during and immediately after initialization and items with children that Sitecore often accesses as a group. Sitecore maintains those caches over the life of the application.

Each database prefetch cache entry represents an item in a database. Database prefetch cache entries include all field values for all versions of that item, and information about the parent and children of the item.

The purpose of this cache is of course to trade longer startup times for faster load times at runtime.

Please have a look on bellow picture to see how cache layers are organized:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at this article, @hisaam has explained it in very detailed and powerful way. And how to configure each of it.

https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/05/07/sitecore-cache/

You can learn more at:

http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/Developers/Articles/2009/07/CachingOverview.aspx

Also enabling `HTTP Response Headers` in the IIS helps a lot in caching static pages.