# Why is Prefetch data(master) cleared by DefaultScavengeStrategy?

Tags: caching

In CM logs I occasionally see Prefetch data(master) cleared by DefaultScavengeStrategy:

> 7744 20:32:18 WARN  SqlDataProvider - Prefetch data(master) cache is
>   cleared by
>   Sitecore.Caching.Generics.Cache`1+DefaultScavengeStrategy[[Sitecore.Data.ID,
>   Sitecore.Kernel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] strategy. Cache running size was 90 MB.

My understanding is that Prefetch cache is filled one time during application startup and should remain immutable for the reminder of application life. Here are some existing responses that seem to confirm that:

1. [How to refresh prefetch cache?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11101/how-to-refresh-prefetch-cache/11105#11105)

> Sitecore populate prefetch catches just at application
>   inititialization, and it maintains it during the lifetime of the
>   application. **Is not possible to update after you run the app and the
>   prefetch cache is already initialized**.

2. [When does prefetch cache get re-populated after publishing?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10594/when-does-prefetch-cache-get-re-populated-after-publishing/10596#10596)

> **Prefetch cache is not repopulated after a publish, it is repopulated
>   just when you restart your site**.

However the log entry shows otherwise. I understand why other caches might be cleared by DefaultScavengeStrategy but I do not understand why Prefetch cache would be cleared by it.

Please help me to understand this log entry.

Thank you.

**Update 1:**

There is an extensive answer regarding the DefaultScavengeStrategy [Log file warning about caching and DefaultScavengeStrategy](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6644/log-file-warning-about-caching-and-defaultscavengestrategy), however it does not explain why it applies to prefetch cache. According to the other two answers I have quoted in the original message, prefetch cache should only be modified at application start up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log file warning about caching and DefaultScavengeStrategy](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6644/log-file-warning-about-caching-and-defaultscavengestrategy)

Comment: Hi Vlad, it is not a duplicate since the referenced post does not reference prefech caches. However it is a great resource to learn about scavenge strategy. Thank you.